# Booting with `cgroup: cgroup2: unknown option "nsdelegate"` prevents any graphics from appearing

Tags: debian, troubleshooting, cgroups

I recently updated my Linux 4.9.0-8 debian 6.3.0. However, when I restarted my machine, ended up having the message in the title. Preventing me from accessing the graphical terminal. I can't access my files which is very serious. All icons and images fail to load. I can't open any windows but GNOME seems to work as if it were normal.

I've tried to update GRUB via recovery mode but other than that, I don't have many ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reconfigured my packages via recovery mode using my user account.

```
$ sudo dpkg -configure -a
```

Comment: What, _all_ your packages?